# Retroactively applying a Piwik goal to visitors

Tags: goal-tracking, matomo

I started receiving a large (for me) amount of traffic on one of my pages yesterday.  Today I thought that it would be useful to track goals from that page -- there's a link to my blog from it.

I added the 'visited external link' goal to Piwik, and new visits are being recorded.  However, it seems to me that there must be enough data in the database to retroactively apply the goal to past users -- is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Is not possible to apply goals retroactively. You can read in the [piwik forum](http://forum.piwik.org/read.php?2,85347).

The goals only apply to new visits.